# SQL Group By - Generate multiple aggregate columns from single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, grouping, aggregate

I would like to group by Company & Date and generate count columns for 2 separate values (Flag=Y and Flag=N).
Input table looks like this:

```
Company  Date   Flag
------- ------- -----
001      201201  Y
001      201201  N
001      201202  N
001      201202  N
001      201202  Y
```

The output should look like this:

```
Company Date   Count_Y Count_N
------- ------ ------- -------
001     201201  1       1
001     201202  1       2
```

How can I write the SQL query?
Any kind of help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the schema for this table? More specifically, Do you have any more columns besides Company, Date and Flag?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it using correlated subqueries like this:

```
SELECT 
  Company, 
  Date, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable AS T1 
     WHERE T1.Flag='Y' AND T1.Company=T2.Company AND T1.Date=T2.Date) AS Count_Y,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable AS T1 
     WHERE T1.Flag='N' AND T1.Company=T2.Company AND T1.Date=T2.Date) AS Count_N
FROM MyTable AS T2
GROUP BY Company, Date
```

You can also do it more concisely, but perhaps with (arguably) slighly less readability using the `SUM` trick:

```
SELECT 
  Company, 
  Date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Flag='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Y,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Flag='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_N,
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Company, Date
```

In Oracle/PLSQL, the `DECODE` function can be used to replace the `CASE` for the even more concise:

```
SELECT 
  Company, 
  Date, 
  SUM(DECODE(Flag,'Y',1,0)) AS Count_Y,
  SUM(DECODE(Flag,'N',1,0)) AS Count_N,
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Company, Date
```

Comment: @msmucker0526, added the word (arguably), since it is subjective

Comment: Well its one scan vs multiple, so logically in this case perhaps its safe to say it should perform better. Also is DECODE present in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @Nitin, nope, `DECODE` is Oracle's PLSQL.

Comment: If you're going to refer to other SQL Syntaxes for SUM\CASE you might as well go with the most concise which is MySQL `SUM( Flag = 'Y') Count_Y, SUM (Flag ='N') Count_N`

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael Goldshteyn. I appreciate a lot your answer with different approaches. Both work fine.I find the second one more readable.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an identifier/key for this table, then you can pivot it like this:

```
SELECT 
  [Company], 
  [Date], 
  [Y] Count_Y, 
  [N] Count_N
  FROM Company
PIVOT 
  (COUNT([ID]) FOR FLAG IN ([Y],[N])) pvt
```

Where `ID` is your identifier for the table `Company`.

Fiddle with the code [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd15c/3/0)

---

If you do not have an identifier/key for the table and Company, Date and Flag are the only columns you have, then you can do a `PIVOT` on the count of the `Flag` itself like @ConradFrix has suggested in the comments:

```
SELECT 
  [Company], 
  [Date], 
  [Y] Count_Y, 
  [N] Count_N
  FROM Company
PIVOT 
  (COUNT(FLAG) FOR FLAG IN ([Y],[N])) pvt
```

Comment: The Pivot is meant for grouping.

Comment: You could just do `COUNT(FLAG) FOR FLAG IN ` [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5b6b/3)

Comment: @ConradFrix - tried that, but if you have even a single column besides the 3 in the table, then you don't get 2 rows like you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The source table has many other columns and it does not have an ID field. While using PIVOT is a plausible options, Michael's solution fits my needs better.

Comment: If none of the other columns are unique, then you have a badly designed table. If any of the other columns are unique, then you can use that column as the ID column. Using `PIVOT` may seem unnerving at first, but `PIVOT` was introduced specifically to handle situations like yours. You can compare the performance of each and see which one is better.