# Add aggregation as new column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a new column based on the aggregation result. For example, the input data (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359054/sql-group-by-generate-multiple-aggregate-columns-from-single-column)) as below:

```
Company  Date   Flag
------- ------- -----
001      201201  Y
001      201201  N
001      201202  N
001      201202  N
001      201202  Y
```

The output I would like to have is

```
Company  Date   Flag  Percentage
------- ------- ----- ----------
001      201201  Y       0.5
001      201201  N       0.5
001      201202  N       0.66
001      201202  Y       0.66
001      201202  Y       0.66
```

That is, I need to join the aggregation (Percentage of Y in Flag column) back to the original table based on `Company` and `Date`.

Note that this is only a toy data. In my real work, I have to join lots of tables to obtain the desired one and find some aggregations. What I did is like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    /* Lots of joins go here to obtain Table A */
) AS A
JOIN (
    SELECT Percentage
    FROM (
       /* Percentage aggregation from Table A */
    ) AS P 
) AS B
ON A.xxx = B.xx
```

The problem is that I will have to generate Table A again when calculating the aggregation `Percentage`. Is it possible to join the aggregation back to the desired table without regenerating the desired table twice? Thanks.

Comment: you could do a select t.* from ( your entire query here ) t and than you have access to all fields from t without having to regenerate anything

Comment: Is there any specific reason why don't create a view basing on Your tables?

Comment: Pretty certain you do what you are after with [window functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), e.g. `Percentage = 1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Company, Date)`

Comment: @Tyron78, I am building SSRS report and I have no permission to build any view.

Comment: @GuidoG, I can do that but how can I merge it back based on, for example, `Company` and `Date`?

Comment: @GarethD, thanks. But actually what I want to find is the percentage of `Flag = Y`. The example above is a little bit ambiguous. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percent of Flags = Y

```
Declare @YourTable table (Company varchar(25),Date int, Flag varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('001',201201,'Y'),
('001',201201,'N'),
('001',201202,'N'),
('001',201202,'N'),
('001',201202,'Y')

Select *
      ,Pct = cast(sum(case when Flag='Y' then 1.0 else 0 end) over (Partition By Company,Date)/count(*) over (Partition By Company,Date) as decimal(10,2))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Company Date    Flag    Pct
001 201201      Y       0.50
001 201201      N       0.50
001 201202      N       0.33
001 201202      N       0.33
001 201202      Y       0.33
```

Comment: Thanks so much, John. This really helps!

Comment: @AndersonZhu Happy to help. But GarethD was there first in his comment.  Then we both learned of the FLAG condition.  Only a small twist to his original comment